# Python zipfile.extract() doesn't extract all files

Tags: python, zip, extract

I'm trying to extract zipped folder using code found here.

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:

    for member in zf.infolist():
        words = member.filename.split('/')
        path = dest_dir
        for word in words[:-1]:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        zf.extract(member, path)
```

But when trying to extract, for example, wordpress.zip with directory structure
wordpress/
-wp-content/
---somefile.php
-wp-config.php
-index.php
I only get the files in folder below root folder or wordpress/ in this case. So i get wordpress/wp-content/somefile.php but not the files in the wordpress/ folder itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first place to look is [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile-objects):

```
ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])
```

Applying that to your situation, I'd try:

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        zf.extractall(dest_dir)
```

Comment: It looks like the protection exists in 2.7.4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

`unzip`, defined below, is what you want.

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        zf.extractall(dest_dir)
```