# zipfile.ZipFile only extracting one folder

Tags: python, module, zip, shutil

I have this code

```
def downloadupdate():
    url = 'http://myurl.com/o/test/list.zip'
    destination = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super.zip')
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,destination)
    time.sleep(40)

    updatezip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super.zip')
    extractupdate = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.test/')
    oldfav = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.test/test')
    yeszip = os.path.exists(updatezip)
    shutil.rmtree(oldfav, ignore_errors=False)
    time.sleep(10)
    if yeszip:
        gh = open(updatezip, 'rb')
        zp = zipfile.ZipFile(gh)
        for name in zp.namelist():
            zp.extract(name, extractupdate)
            gh.close()
            time.sleep(3)
    else:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(some text, sometext,()")

downloadupdate()
```

The zip file downloads correctly
the zip file saves in the correct location
the  deletes correctly
inside super.zip there are 12 directories and in each if these twelve directories is test.txt file
When I extract Super.zip it only extracts one of the twelve directories and that extracted directory is empty. Could it be that I need to somehow stop or close the shutil process? and as its extracting, its being erased at the same time by shutil?
Could anyone please shed some light on my fault here please. Thankyou

Comment: Without testing, tough to see what's going on.  That said, trying using `zp.extractall(path, pwd)` instead of extract.   I don't see where you set the current working directory so there is a good chance it's extracting to whatever that is.  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l1030

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483775/python-zipfile-extract-doesnt-extract-all-files possible solution

Answer (score 0):

ok so it is now working Thankyou david a GIRISH

```
def downloadupdate():
    url = 'http://myurl.com/o/test/list.zip'
    destination = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super.zip')
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,destination)
    time.sleep(40)

    updatezip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super.zip')
    extractupdate = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.test/')
    oldfav = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.test/test')
    yeszip = os.path.exists(updatezip)
    shutil.rmtree(oldfav, ignore_errors=False)
    time.sleep(10)
    if yeszip:
        gh = open(updatezip, 'rb')
        zp = zipfile.ZipFile(gh)
        zp.extractall(extractupdate)
        gh.close()
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(some text, sometext,()")

downloadupdate()
```